# How can i2cdetect display all I²C addresses as used?

Tags: i2c

I've ran into a strange issue with the I²C port of my Raspi 3B: After connecting a [TDA7318](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000150.pdf) audio mixer chip, some other I²C slaved were no longer recognised. So I disconnected the TDA to restore the last working configuration to come up with `i2cdetect` telling me that there is suddenly a device under every possible address:

```
pi@autoradio:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 
20: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 
30: 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 
40: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c UU 4e 4f 
50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f 
60: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 UU 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 
70: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

The problem is: I can't do anything with my I²C devices (save for the sound card under address 4D) any more. What's wrong here?

**UPDATE:** Following [this instruction](http://www.pibits.net/learning/resetting-i2c-driver-raspberry-pi.php) (using `i2c_bcm2835`) does NOT help. The issue persists. Is maybe the fact that the TDA has a Vcc of +9 V related to my issue?

**UPDATE #2:** Disconnecting all I²C slaves save for the two HATs (sound card & UPS) does not help either. Does that mean that the unwanted connection between SDA and GND is in one of the HATs?

**UPDATE #3:** After removing everything (including the HATs), the ``gpiotest* utility showed me some trouble with the pull-up resistor on pin #2:

```
Testing...
Write 1 to gpio 2 failed.
Pull up on gpio 2 failed.
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: 2
```

**UPDATE #4:** After another hint, I measured the voltage on the SDA pin: 0.1 V. The resistance between SDA and the 3.3 V pin is 1800 Ω. Is something wrong with the pull-up resistor on the SDA pin?

Comment: Run the test I suggested.

Comment: Do I also have to remove the two HATs before running the test?

Answer (score 2):

It's a wiring problem.

You have something pulling the SDA line to ground.  This makes it appear that a device is present at every address.

The test you have run confirms that GPIO2 has been destroyed.  Presumably 9V has found its way to GPIO2 from the audio module.  A possibility is there is a pull-up on the module to Vcc.  Anyhow, you need a new Pi.  If you want to continue using that module you will need to do  more research on its electrical characteristics.

Comment: Isn't such a state dangerous to the Pi's I²C circuitry?

Comment: Not in itself.  You pull a GPIO to ground with a switch to signal low, and pull it to 3V3 with a switch to signal high.  It's only a problem if nothing external is pulling the line to ground as that indicates an internal problem (or the GPIO has been set to the wrong mode).

Comment: OK, I can exclude the wrong mode, as I haven't changed the config before this issue appeared. What puzzles me, though, is: When I restore the wiring (I'm using a breadboard) to the previous state (with the TDA disconnected from the I²C bus and everathing else left untouched in the last working state), I still get the error.

Comment: Try https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing with nothing connected.

Comment: Results see above. And: The TDA datasheet tells me: "Pull-up resistors to positive
supply voltage must be connected." But as the Pi has its own ones, this should be no problem?!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you disconnected the audio mixer chip you also disconnected the pullup resistors on SDA and SCL. Those resistors are **required** for proper operation of the I2C bus.

Comment: Save for the mixer chip, all I²C slaves I'm using are wither HATs, or breakout boards, which should be equipped with pull-up resistors.

Comment: "Should be..." Can you verify that?

Comment: The Pi has hard-wired pull-ups on SDA/SCL.  No more should be used.

Comment: Both breakouts have their own pull-ups.